# What's the most elegant way to check for the existence of a command line tool on the system from Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For reference, the Bash equivalents are discussed here: [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-to-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

I've been doing something like

```
if `which commandname` =~ /commandname/
  # do stuff
end
```

but I'm wondering if there is something a little cleaner.

Comment: perhaps `if File.executable?(\`which commandname\`)`

Comment: Just invoke the command, and catch the exception raised if the command doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
system("ls")
#=> true

system("ls wrong params")
#=> false

system("lss")
#=> nil

if system("your cmd")
  puts "yey!"
else
  puts "oups"
end
```